# How to Create/Insert a new record of the objects AccountAccountRelation and PartyRoleRelation?

Tags: apex, permissions, security, dml, standard-objects

these 2 objects **AccountAccountRelation** and **PartyRoleRelation** have been added to our project recently and I don't know why I cannot create a record of these objects.

> - When I want to set the value of a field of any of these objects, I keep getting this error: ***FIELD_NAME** is not a writeable field.*

> - When I remove all the fields that cause the error above(previous point), I now receive an error telling me that I can not insert the record.

My user has the **System Administration** profile and has been assigned a permission set that permits me to work with these objects. See the screenshots below:

**AccountAccountRelation:**
[image]

**PartyRoleRelation:**
[image]

How to fix these issues, please?

**NOTE: Automotive and Group Membership are enabled.**